Help in solving a logarithm equation: $\log_{(4/3)}(2\log_{10}(\sqrt{x^2+7})(\log_8(10)))+\log_2(\log_4(x^2+7))=2 $
I am stuck on this question

$$\log_{(4/3)}(2\log_{10}(\sqrt{x^2+7})(\log_8(10)))+\log_2(\log_4(x^2+7))=2 $$

Initially, I made an attempt to simplfy the argument of $\log_{4/3}(.)$ term on the left side by using power identity which gives the left -hand side as
$$\log_{(4/3)}(\log_{10}({x^2+7})(\log_8(10)))+\log_2(\log_4(x^2+7)) $$
or
$$\log_{(4/3)}(\log_{10}({x^2+7})(\log_8(10)))+\log_2(\log_4(x^2+7)) $$
Which can be written as
$$\log_{(4/3)}(\log_8(10)^{\log_{10}({x^2+7})}))+\log_2(\log_4(x^2+7)) $$
From change of base, we have this as
$$\log_{(4/3)}(\log_{8}({x^2+7})))+\log_2(\log_4(x^2+7)) $$
Finally suibstituting $\log_2(x^2+7)=t$,the equation simplifies to
$$\log_{(4/3)}\left(\frac{t}{3}\right)+\log_2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)=2$$
I'm not sure on how to solve this equation. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Some handy rules to not reinvent the wheel by: $\log_{a} b\cdot \log_b c = \log_a c$ (so $\log_8 10 \times \log_{10}...$)  and $\log_{a^k} b = \frac {\log_a b}k$.  You came up with those on your own but....

@fleablood Oops. Definitely overlooked the properties you mentioned. But hey I can play the 'I'm still learning' card. Thanks BTW?

Let reduce to the same base using that
$$\log_a b = \frac{\log_c b}{\log_c a}$$
that is
$$\log_{(4/3)}\left(\frac{t}{3}\right)+\log_2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)=2 \iff \frac{\log_2 t-\log_2 3}{\log_2 \frac 43}+\log_2 t-1=2$$
and then solving for $\log_2 t$.

Thanks so much. Silly me. I was apparently missing the obvious.

Here is another way to solve your equation:
$\log_{\frac43}\!\!\left[2\log_{10}\left(\!\sqrt{\!x^2\!\!+\!7}\right)\big(\!\log_8\!10\big)\right]\!+\log_2\!\big[\log_4\left(x^2\!\!+\!7\right)\big]\!=\!2$
$\!\!\!\!\log_{\frac43}\!\!\!\left[\!\dfrac{\log_{10}\!\!\left(\!\sqrt{\!x^2\!\!+\!7}\right)^{\!2}}{\log_{10}\!8}\!\right]\!\!+\!\log_2\!\!\left[\!\dfrac12\log_2\left(x^2\!\!+\!7\right)\!\right]\!\!=\!\log_{\frac43}\!\!\dfrac43\!+\!\log_2\!2$
$\!\!\!\!\log_{\frac43}\!\!\big[\log_8\!\left(x^2\!\!+\!7\right)\!\big]\!\!-\!\log_{\frac43}\!\!\dfrac43\!+\!\log_2\!\left[\!\dfrac12\log_2\left(x^2\!\!+\!7\right)\!\right]\!\!-\!\log_2\!2\!=\!0$
$\log_{\frac43}\!\!\left[\dfrac34\log_8\!\left(x^2\!\!+\!7\right)\right]\!+\log_2\!\left[\dfrac14\log_2\left(x^2\!\!+\!7\right)\right]=0$
$\log_{\frac43}\!\!\left[\dfrac14\log_2\!\left(x^2\!\!+\!7\right)\right]\!+\log_2\!\left[\dfrac14\log_2\left(x^2\!\!+\!7\right)\right]=0$
$\dfrac{\log_2\!\!\left[\dfrac14\log_2\!\left(x^2\!\!+\!7\right)\right]}{\log_2\!\frac43}\!+\log_2\!\left[\dfrac14\log_2\left(x^2\!\!+\!7\right)\right]=0$
from which it follows that
$\log_2\!\!\left[\dfrac14\log_2\!\left(x^2\!+7\right)\right]=0$
$\dfrac14\log_2\!\left(x^2\!+7\right)=1$
$\log_2\!\left(x^2\!+7\right)=4$
$x^2\!+7=16$
$x=\pm3\,.$
